Laravel authorization returns 403 even if policy returns true
I'm using Laravel 11, Vue 3 and InertiaJS.
I'm trying to get authorization to work but it keeps returning 403 even if the policy returns true.
The Inertia Link conditionally shows (successfully so) the link to the edit form for the given post:
<Link
    v-if="user.can.update"
    :href="route('posts.edit', { post: post })"
>
    Update
</Link>

Both routes below fail, I've tried with and without middleware('auth').
Route::get( 'posts/{post}/edit',  [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('posts.edit')
    ->middleware('auth')->can('update', 'post');

Route::get( 'posts/{post}/edit',  [PostController::class, 'edit'])->name('posts.edit')
    ->can('update', 'post');

and the PostPolicy:
public function update(User $user, Post $post): bool
{
    return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}

dd($user->id === $post->user_id); // returns true

The logs dont seem to pick up the 403 message either so I don't see the stack trace there. I'm at a complete loss, what is the issue with this?
I tried with and without middleware 'auth' but with no luck. Putting a Gate::authorize within the controller immediately did not seem to work either.

return $post->user->is($user)
make sure the relationship is set for above example. to test if the policy is hitting just write
 return true;
and see if it performs if not the policy is not hitting.
